# I need to Prefetch data but only last in django

Tags: django, django-models

```python
  class AppliedEvent(models.Model):

    event_type = models.ForeignKey(EventType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='applied_events', null=True)
    seedbed = models.ForeignKey(Seedbed, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='applied_events')
    seed = models.ForeignKey(Seed, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='applied_events', null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='applied_events', null=True)

class AppliedEventTime(models.Model):

    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    event = models.ForeignKey(AppliedEvent, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='times')
    applied_by = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='applied_times', null=True)
```

User have ability to add new event time by creating new AppliedEventTime instance.

```python
class AppliedEventMixin:
    request: Any
    def get_queryset(self) -> QuerySet:
        return AppliedEvent.objects.filter(user_id=self.context.request.user).select_related(
        'user', 'event_type', 'seedbed', 'seed'
        ).only('user__username', 'event_type__name', 'seedbed__id', 'seed__id').prefetch_related(
        'times'
            )
```

This is my query set mixin for django-extra controller

```python
@api_controller('/applied_event', auth=JWTAuth(), permissions=[IsAuthenticated])
class AppliedEventController(AppliedEventMixin):
    @route.get('/applied_event/{event_id}', tags=['applied_event'], response=AppliedEventOutSchema)
    def event_by_id(self, event_id: int):
        event = get_object_or_404(self.get_queryset(), pk=event_id)

        return event
```

This is controller for API and point.

```python
class EventTypeNameSchema(Schema):
    id: int
    name: str

AppliedEventTimeSchema = create_schema(AppliedEventTime, exclude=['id', 'event'], custom_fields=[('applied_by', UserOutSchema, None)])

class UserOutSchema(Schema):
    id: int
    username: str

class AppliedEventOutSchema(ModelSchema):
    event_type: EventTypeNameSchema
    user: UserOutSchema
    times: List[AppliedEventTimeSchema]
    
    class Config:
        model = AppliedEvent
        include = ['id', 'seedbed', 'seed']
```

This is my schema.

I am trying to prefetch only the latest added AppliedEventTime instance related to AppliedEvent in my Django project. I have a AppliedEvent model that has a foreign key to AppliedEventTime model and a user foreign key, the AppliedEventTime model has a foreign key to the AppliedEvent model and a user foreign key.

**my question is, how can i prefetch only latest added AppliedEventTime instance related to AppliedEvent?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `order_by('-id')` to order the `AppliedEventTime` instances in descending order and `use first()` method to get the latest added instance.

```
class AppliedEventMixin:
    request: Any
    def get_queryset(self) -> QuerySet:
        return AppliedEvent.objects.filter(user_id=self.context.request.user).select_related(
        'user', 'event_type', 'seedbed', 'seed'
        ).only('user__username', 'event_type__name', 'seedbed__id', 'seed__id').prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('times', queryset=AppliedEventTime.objects.order_by('-id').first())
            )
```

or, alternatively what you can do is modify the class `AppliedEventMixin` to prefetch only the latest added `AppliedEventTime` instance related to `AppliedEvent`. Replace the line with `Prefetch...` in the above solution i provided with:

```
Prefetch('times', queryset=AppliedEventTime.objects.latest())
```